# JQuery Validate validating single field before the rest in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-validate

I'm sure this is something really stupid, but I'm having an issue with the jQuery validator plugin, which I've used plenty in the past, but never before on a Wordpress site. I'm running into an odd problem right now where the first time clicking the submit button triggers only a single field (the "nomsalutation" field, to be specific) to be validated.

Then, the second time that I click the button causes the rest of the required fields to be validated.

I'm kind of at a loss as to what could even cause this... it doesn't seem like script load timing issue because there is at least something being validated on the first click of the submit button. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Here's the main page file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!--BEGIN BOOTSTRAP -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/6aecacc1-7701-4d30-aa30-2e887c6d190d.css"/>


<!--END BOOTSTRAP -->


<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>


<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/js/datepicker.js"></script>


<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>

<!--BEGIN NAV BAR-->
<div style="height:30px; width:980px; margin:auto">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
</div>
<!--END NAV BAR-->

<div class="title-container">
    <div style="width:980px; margin:auto">
        <div class="page-heading" style="padding-top:30px; padding-left:30px">
        <?php the_field('page_title'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="page-subheading" style="padding-top:0px; padding-left:30px">
        <?php the_field('page_subtitle'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--BEGIN MAIN CONTAINER-->
<div class="container-main">

<div style="clear:both; height:30px"></div>

<div style="padding:30px; background-color:#dacd61; margin-bottom:30px">

<div class="quote" style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px">
<?php the_field('nominate_callout'); ?> 
</div>

</div>


<div class="feature-heading" style="width: 980px; height: 47px; border-bottom: 2px solid #b11f16; background-color: #fff; padding-top: 8px; padding-left: 30px;">Submit a Nominee</div>
<div class="feature-text" style="width: 980px; background-color: #fff; padding: 30px;">

<form method="post" id="registerForm" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/securesend.php">

<span class="feature-heading-small">Nominee Information</span>

<span style="font-size:12px; font-style:italic"><font color="#dacd61">*</font> Required</span><br>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name of Nominee">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name of Nominee">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input class="form-control" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" placeholder="DOB (mm/dd/yyyy)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input class="form-control" name="deathdate" id="deathdate" placeholder="DOD (if applicable)">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Primary Company Affiliation">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input class="form-control" name="invention" id="invention" placeholder="Common Invention Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input class="form-control" name="patentnum" id="patentnum" placeholder="Patent # of Invention">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:40px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div>
        <textarea style="max-width: 100%;" name="inventiondetails" id="inventiondetails" class="form-control" class="form-width" placeholder="Invention Explanation and Impact - Please provide information about the nominee and his or her invention. Focus on the invention’s effect on the public welfare, its advancement of the useful arts in the United States and its overall economic impact."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<span class="feature-heading-small">Contact Information for Living Nominee</span><br>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">    
                    <input class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7" style="float: right; padding:0;">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="form-control" name="street" id="street" placeholder="Street Address">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">--State--</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    </div>
</div>

<span class="feature-heading-small">Contact Information for Nominator</span><br>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <select class="form-control" name="nomsalutation" id="nomsalutation">
                                <option value="">--Prefix--</option>
                                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                                <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                                <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                                <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
                                <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
                                <option value="Sr.">Sr.</option>
                                <option value="Rev.">Rev.</option>
                                <option value="Rev. Dr.">Rev. Dr.</option>
                            </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input class="form-control" name="NomFirst" id="NomFirst" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input class="form-control" name="NomLast" id="NomLast" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input name="NomCompany" id="NomCompany" class="form-control" placeholder="Nominator Company">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input name="NomPhone" id="NomPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Nominator Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-asterix">*</div><input class="form-control" name="NomEmail" id="NomEmail" placeholder="Nominator Email">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input class="form-control" name="NomStreet" id="NomStreet" placeholder="Nominator Street Address">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input class="form-control" name="NomCity" id="NomCity" placeholder="Nominator City">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select name="NomState" id="NomState" class="form-control">
                                                                            <option value="">--State--</option>
                                                                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                                                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                                                            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                                                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                                                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                                                                            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                                                            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                                                            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                                                            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                                                            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                                                            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                                                            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                                                            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                                                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                                                            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                                                            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                                                            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                                                            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                                                            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                                                            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                                                            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                                                            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                                                            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                                                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                                                            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                                                            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                                                            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                                                            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                                                            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                                                            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                                                            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                                                            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                                                            <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                                                            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                                                            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                                                            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                                                            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                                                            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                                                            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                                                            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                                                            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                                                            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                                                            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                                                            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                                                            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                                                            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                                                            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                                                            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                                                            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                                                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                                                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                                                    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input class="form-control" name="NomZip" id="NomZip" placeholder="Nominator Zip">
    </div>  
</div>

<input type="submit" class="button-yellow" value="SUBMIT" style="margin-top: 40px;">



<!-- <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="254" title="Submit a Nominee"]'); ?> -->

</div>

</form>

</div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both; height:30px"></div>

<!--END MAIN CONTAINER-->
```

Here's the formvalid.js file (nothing fancy just yet):

```
    $("#registerForm").validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            required: true
        },

        last_name: {
            required: true
        },

        invention: {
            required: true
        },

        inventiondetails: {
            required: true
        },

        nomsalutation: {
            required: true
        },

        NomFirst: {
            required: true
        },

        NomLast: {
            required: true
        },

        NomEmail: {
            required: true
        },

        NomPhone: {
            required: true
        },

        title: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

And finally, here's the footer.php file:

```
    <!--BEGIN FOOTER-->
<div style="height:148px; background-image:url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/bg_footer.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; min-width:980px">

<div style="width:980px; height:148px; margin:auto; background-image:url(<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/images/footer_bg-glow.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top center">

<div class="row" style="padding-top:37px; width:980px">
</div>

</div>

</div>
<!--END FOOTER-->

<!--BEGIN BOOTSTRAP -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/js/formvalid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/js/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/js/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></script>

<script>
  //DATEPICKER JQUERY CALL
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#deathdate" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: '01/01/1980',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1700:2015"
    });

    $( "#birthdate" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: '01/01/1980',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "1700:2015"
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
$(".searchinput").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        rowCount();
        searchResults(0);
    }
});
</script>
<script>
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
    input.removeClass('placeholder');
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
  }
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
    }
  })
});
</script>

<!--END BOOTSTRAP -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** call `.validate()` before the plugin has been included.

If you are including the jQuery Validation script in the footer, then the `.validate()` method **must** come sometime *after* the include.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/formsend/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

.....

<script>
    $("#registerForm").validate({
        rules: {...
```

---

Also, since jQuery is already included within most WordPress templates, you should study the `wp_enqueue_script` documentation to make sure you're not accidentally including jQuery multiple times by the way you've put it in your footer.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script